# How to achieve Conjunction of type traits

Tags: c++, c++17

```
template <typename T, typename... Tc>
constexpr bool ConjuctionofConvertible () noexcept
{
    return std::conjunction<std::is_convertible_v<T, Tc>...>::value;
}
```

Getting error:

```
Error   no return statement in constexpr function   
Error   template argument for template type parameter must be a type
```

Comment: Did any of the answers help you to solve the problem?

Answer (score 7):

You just need to use `is_convertible` instead of the helper variable `is_convertible_v`:

```
template <typename T, typename... Tc>
constexpr bool ConjuctionofConvertible () noexcept
{
    return std::conjunction<std::is_convertible<T, Tc>...>::value;
}
```

or

```
template <typename T, typename... Tc>
constexpr bool ConjuctionofConvertible () noexcept
{
    return std::conjunction_v<std::is_convertible<T, Tc>...>;
}
```

See this possible implementation of [`conjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction):

```
template<class...> struct conjunction : std::true_type { };

template<class B1> struct conjunction<B1> : B1 { };

template<class B1, class... Bn>
struct conjunction<B1, Bn...> 
    : std::conditional_t<bool(B1::value), conjunction<Bn...>, B1> {};
                              ^^^^^^^^^
```

You'll notice that it requires a type (with a `value` member), not a `bool`.

---

Other interesting notes, copied and edited from [`std::conjuction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction):

`std::conjunction` was added in C++17 and so was [*fold expressions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). One reason for using `conjuction` over a fold expression is that
`conjunction` is short-circuiting.

If there is a template type argument `Bi` with `bool(Bi::value) == false`, then instantiating `conjunction<B1, ..., BN>::value` does not require the instantiation of `Bj::value` for `j > i`.

The short-circuit instantiation differentiates `conjunction` from fold expressions: a fold expression like `(... && Bs::value)` instantiates every `B` in `Bs`, while `std::conjunction_v<Bs...>` stops instantiation once the value can be determined. This is particularly useful if the later type is expensive to instantiate or can cause a hard error when instantiated with the wrong type.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use `std::conjunction` in your example, a simple *fold-expression* should be enough.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename... Tc>
constexpr bool AllConvertible () noexcept {
  return (std::is_convertible_v<T, Tc> && ...);
}
```